# Recasting a system into a a system of first-order differential equations

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations

> Consider a particle of mass $m$ moving in the plane subject to a force given by $\textbf{f} (t, x, y) = (f(t, x, y), g(t, x, y))$. The coordinates $x(t)$ and $y(t)$ of its position satisfy
>   $$
> m \ddot{x} = f(t, x(t), y(t))
> $$
>   and
>   $$
> m \ddot{y} = g(t, x(t), y(t))
> $$
>   Recast this system as a system of four first-order differential equations

So the problem I have is just starting the question; I don't know which first-order differential equations I should be trying to find, and I can't figure out which ones it should be, or even how to begin.

Answer (score 2):

The standard way to do this is to relabel $\dot{x}$ and $\dot{y}$ as separate variables. Set
$$ u = \dot{x}, \qquad v = \dot{y}, $$
then
$$ m\dot{u} = f(t,x(t),y(t)) \\
m\dot{v} = g(t,x(t),y(t)). $$
The equations we used to define $u$ and $v$ are first-order, as are second two equations, and this is clearly equivalent to the original system.

Since the question doesn't ask for any properties, any first-order system you can find that is equivalent will do.